# "Redemption Helper Outlook Extension" add-in that cannot be loaded

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

I'm facing [troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75565917/redemption-error-microsoft-exchange-is-not-available-after-moving-mailboxes-t) migrating some mailboxes from Exchange 2010 to Exchange 2016 because they are still used by an old application as part of some B2B flows. The application uses an old version of the **Redemption.dll** library (5.0.0.2174) to access mailboxes, get attachments and move the incoming e-mails to a subfolder “ELABORATED”. Everything is working on a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. Please don’t comment…

Starting Outlook after upgrading from 2010 to 2013 with the latest updates (version meeting requirements on both Exchange and OS sides), we start to see an error related to the "Redemption Helper Outlook Extension": add-in cannot be loaded and has been disabled by Outlook.

Does this mean that the version of Redemption is not compatible with the new Outlook?
Is this component directly involved on Redemption library functionalities?

I haven't done anything since I'm investigating how the library works.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Redemption (for a quite a few years now) no longer install itself as an Outlook addin.

Make sure Redemption is still in the location where Outlook expects it or that you unregister the old version of Redemption first using `regsvr32.exe /u`.